# Eclipse: unknown device in Devices view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

At some point, after attempting to run an application on the emulator I've opened in advance, while launching, it has showed this:

> [image]

I've launched only one emulator, the second one. The first one, with a warning sign, has appeared out of nowhere. I don't even own a physical Android device.

OK, I chose the right one. Afterwards decided to check the Devices view, which was looking like this:

> [image]

No other signs of this device existing anywhere can be found (by me, at least). But it's annoying. Anyone can give a clue where did it come from and how to get rid of it?

Update :

Now I cannot even launch the app on the running emulator (log from the console), Following are the error logs:

```
[2014-01-26 15:35:12 - JavaBook] Android Launch!
[2014-01-26 15:35:12 - JavaBook] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-26 15:35:12 - JavaBook] Performing kt.play.javabook.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-26 15:35:12 - JavaBook] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-26 15:35:15 - JavaBook] Uploading JavaBook.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2014-01-26 15:36:20 - JavaBook] Installing JavaBook.apk...
[2014-01-26 15:38:20 - JavaBook] Success!
[2014-01-26 15:38:20 - JavaBook] Starting activity kt.play.javabook.MainActivity on device emulator-5556
[2014-01-26 15:38:21 - JavaBook] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=kt.play.javabook/.MainActivity }
[2014-01-26 15:42:21 - JavaBook] ------------------------------
[2014-01-26 15:42:21 - JavaBook] Android Launch!
[2014-01-26 15:42:21 - JavaBook] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-26 15:42:21 - JavaBook] Performing kt.play.javabook.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-26 15:42:21 - JavaBook] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-26 15:42:39 - JavaBook] Uploading JavaBook.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2014-01-26 15:44:00 - JavaBook] Failed to install JavaBook.apk on device 'emulator-5556': timeout
[2014-01-26 15:44:00 - JavaBook] Launch canceled!
[2014-01-26 15:44:22 - JavaBook] ------------------------------
[2014-01-26 15:44:22 - JavaBook] Android Launch!
[2014-01-26 15:44:22 - JavaBook] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-26 15:44:22 - JavaBook] Performing kt.play.javabook.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-26 15:44:22 - JavaBook] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-26 15:44:24 - JavaBook] Uploading JavaBook.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2014-01-26 15:45:44 - JavaBook] Failed to install JavaBook.apk on device 'emulator-5556': timeout
[2014-01-26 15:45:44 - JavaBook] Launch canceled!
[2014-01-26 15:45:51 - JavaBook] ------------------------------
[2014-01-26 15:45:51 - JavaBook] Android Launch!
[2014-01-26 15:45:51 - JavaBook] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-26 15:45:51 - JavaBook] Performing kt.play.javabook.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-26 15:45:51 - JavaBook] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-26 15:45:57 - JavaBook] Uploading JavaBook.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2014-01-26 15:47:26 - JavaBook] Failed to install JavaBook.apk on device 'emulator-5556': timeout
[2014-01-26 15:47:26 - JavaBook] Launch canceled!
```

Also: The LogCat ignores the running emulator, the 5556 one, completely... However, when I try to "Stop Process", the one with the question mark belonging to the 5554 one, the LogCat gets filled up with all sorts of junk.

And also: When I try to telnet to localhost 5554, it informs me that it "Could not open connection to the host, on port 5554: Connect failed". I can telnet to 5556, though (when it's running, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Have you started an emulator, shut it down, then start a second one? if so it's possible that the first emulator never completely shut down.

you can check in the windows task-manager to see if there are multiple instances of the emulator

Comment: That would be logical. However, no, there was only one instance of the emulator in the Task Manager too. At least in Apps section (I have Windows 8.1 installed). Maybe I should look for it in Background processes? If so, what process am I looking for?

What's interesting, if I restart the PC and then open the Eclipse - it is there again!

K.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of the Task Manager, if it helps: 

http://i44.tinypic.com/5kf250.png

Comment: That's definitely strange. Especially since it survives a reboot. Since the task manager lets you know which Emulator it is (Nexus10-APIL18-ARM) you can try to delete this AVD completely and see it that helps  (or even delete all AVDs) and create new ones to see if it helps

Comment: Exactly, although it seems like you still have an emulator running.
try to see if there is some f'd up AVD still lying around on disk. AVDs are typically stored in `C:\Users\UserName\.android\avd` if you see anything there, delete it (backup first). if that doesn't work. try to restart the adb server. just google how to do it, it's really easy

Comment: Yea, it still was there... The folder you've mentioned was empty. I've tried to play with the folder, tried to delete certain files, the folder itself (put it back afterwards), but there was no reaction from the emulator. Tried to restart the adb server, then, to no avail. The "adb devices" command right after the restart shows this: emulator-5554   device. Should it be there?

Comment: It shouldn't be there if you deleted everything. have you tried killing it from the task manager ( end process or right click -> end process tree)

Comment: Sorry for being idle, other stuff took my time, so I've opened Eclipse only today. Funny, but the mysterious device is just gone! No idea what has happened. Well, other devices are gone as well, can't remember if I deleted them or not... Ah well, everything's back to normal. Thanks for all the ideas, Or Bar!

Answer (score 0):

Some times when I start my environment, I can't deploy my application from eclipse to my android device.
Then, I run this code and just works:

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```